# Why is VK_ENTER not working?

Tags: java, awtrobot

So, I am trying to attach a file, and I am able to paste the location of the file using Robot. However, after I paste the path, I want to press enter, but it does not seem to work.

Here is the code that I have right now:

```
WebElement attach = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='a1 aaA aMZ']"));
JavascriptExecutor ai = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
ai.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", attach);
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

Anyone know what is happening?

Comment: Did you check whether the focus is on Open button or not in your file browse dialog box?

Comment: i think you're misusing the word "driver". It doesnt mean what you might think it means ... Java never had direct access to any kind of driver - unless you start using third-party libraries. That'd be really complicated even with native software - usually self-written commlibs have to be used for that because drivers are really isolated from the rest of the operating system world ... basically, they only exist for the kernel itself, noone else.